# how to handle special character(#) in json resonse while fetching data?

Tags: json, react-native

I have a json response which has some special character key value. In react native, when I try to access the data using key value it shows me error because special character not allowed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UoeA.png)

Please visit the image it shows under first array you can see there is a image object which has another array of 4 elements. I expended one array which has two objects inside.

Now I have to access "*#text** to get the url. I wrote it like this

**this.props.albumdata.image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UoeA.png).#text**

but this is invalid because of **#**.

So how can I access the this text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the name of the property using bracket notation.

```
this.props.albumdata.image1[‘#text’]
```